# Generate Sonar Report in XML and CSV file Format

Tags: xml, continuous-integration, sonarqube, export-to-csv

I am using SonarQube 6.4 and I want to generate the report in XML and CSV format. Can anybody tell me how to do that ?

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: Installed SonarQube Server and done the code quality analysis with Eclipse and want to generate the report in xml/CSV format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no native functionality in SonarQube to generate the kind of reports you want. If you really have to have this, you'll need to cobble it together yourself with the results of the [web services](https://sonarcloud.io/web_api). Note that there are some hard-coded limits on the volume of results you can pull from those services, so you won't be able to use them to dump the entire DB.

Comment: Thank you G. Ann for the above suggestions.

Comment: @JitendraKumar if this was helpful, perhaps you could accept it?